# Do I need to use "to" in sentences such as these?

Tags: conjunction-reduction, what-that

> What I want is (to) go to the cinema.
>
> What you should do is (to) shut up and dance.

I know that "to" is frequently omitted in such cases, but if you were to write a formal paper, would you include it or not?

Comment: Previous questions on this: [“When what you really should do is ***”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/120049/), [“All you have to do is read” vs. “All you have to do is to read”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/), [“What I have to do is” + verb inf](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/106058/), [Omitting the last “to” in “All {I need to / have to / must} do is (to?) do something”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/122277/), plus some related questions linked from these. I am open to suggestions which one to merge this one into.

Comment: +1 I love the idea of writing a formal paper about "shut up and dance."

Comment: Thanks for the references, I think it's best explained here:
http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/104546/all-you-have-to-do-is-read-vs-all-you-have-to-do-is-to-read

Answer (score 3):

Your examples are *wh*-clefts. In the words of the ‘Longman Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ *wh*-clefts consist of:

> a clause introduced by a *wh*-word, usually *what*; this clause has
>   its own point of focus, usually at the end of the *wh*-clause
>
> a form of the verb *be*
>
> the specially focused nominal element

The specially focused element in the first example is *to go to the cinema*. This takes the
form of a *to*-infinitive, because as a non-cleft it would occur as *I want to go to the cinema*, and not as *I want go to the cinema*.

The specially focused element in the second example is *shut up and dance*. This takes the form of a bare infinitive, because as a non-cleft it would occur as *You should shut up and dance*, and not as *You should to shut up and dance*. That in turn is because the bare infinitive is required after  modal verbs such as *should*.

Answer (score 2):

> *What I want is **to** go to the cinema.* (grammatical)
> **What I want is go to the cinema.*  (asterisk means ungrammatical)

As Barrie has pointed out, both of the example sentences are [*Wh*-Cleft constructions](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/356440/15299).
That means they have been done things to. This sentence is from the prototype

- *I want (**for me**) to go to the cinema.*  ([Equi](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/284751/15299): same subject for *want* and *go*) ==>
- *I want to go to the cinema.* (*Wh*-Cleft) ==>
- ***What** I want **is** to go the cinema.*

The infinitive complementizer ***to*** in this sentence is still needed
to mark the infinitive clause ***to go the cinema***
on the right side of the fulcrum of cleavage ***is***
(the fulcrum *be* is inserted by the *Wh*-cleft rule);
this balances the embedded *What*-clause *what I want*
on the left side of the fulcrum.
It's that construction balanced on a fulcrum that marks a cleft sentence.

In the second case, however,

> *What you should do is shut up and dance.*

the original has no infinitive complementizer *to*; on the contrary,
the infinitive forms *do, shut (up),* and *dance*
are governed by the modal auxiliary *should*, which is deleted in the downstairs clauses
by conjunction reduction (and not by Equi).
So there is no infinitive complementizer *to*.

- *You should shut up and (**you should**) dance*. (Conjunction Reduction) ==>
- *You should shut up and dance*. (*Wh*-Cleft: adds active pro-verb *do*) ==>
- ***What** you should **do is** shut up and dance*.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you absolutely need *to* in the first example. You **cannot** say:

```
What I want is go cinema.
```

This is not a case where *to* is functioning as a preposition that may be omitted. *To go* is the infinitive form of the verb, which is the form required by that sentence.

The second one should not have the word *to* at all. This sentence is an imperative (a command or a directive). You can distill that sentence down to:

```
Shut up and dance!
```

As for use in a formal paper, I wouldn't use either of them. I would say:

```
I want to go to the cinema.
Just shut up and dance.
```

I don't know what type of formal paper you're writing, but this sounds like dialogue to me.

Comment: Thanks, John, but this didn't answer my question.

Comment: Try to see it all as a whole, like in:
"What I want to do is sing" vs "What I want to do is to sing".

Comment: @MagdalenaBalibreaVich Forgive me, but I believe I addressed the entire question as it was written. If I've missed something, please let me know what that is. When you say *What **I**  want to do is sing,* then the infinitive is needed. You're primary verb is *want.* With that said, if the subject becomes **you** (2nd person singular), it becomes an imperative if you're telling someone what they *should* or *need to* do. In imperatives, *to* should not be used.

Comment: At any rate, you shouldn't use that construction in formal writing if it can be avoided.

Comment: 'What I want is go cinema' would probably be alright if you were speaking to a Cockney (Working-class Londoner).'I can't go toilet' in Cockney-speak, means 'I'm constipated'.

Comment: @Strangerbird I know what Cockney means. I don't believe the asker was inquiring about accents, dialects, colloquial speech, etc. I believe the question was about standard English.

Comment: @John Q Public. Yes I did appreciate that. i just thought they might be interested in the sort of things Cockneys say.

Answer (score -2):

Why not "What I want is **going** to cinema"?

Comment: For starters, because dodging a question is not answering it.

Comment: And to build upon what RegDwight has said, that's not evven close to grammatically correct. You might as well say *What I want is go cinema* if you're going to say that.

Comment: My mistakes, you are absolutely right - too often heard, however. But is "going to the cinema is what I want" not correct ?"mark thorin

Comment: The gerund is a possibility. You could say 'What I want is more cinema-going'. A bit clumsy but grammatically correct.