# Is there a difference between "started to go" and "started going"?

Tags: descriptive-grammar, gerund-vs-infinitive

Is there a meaning difference between *started to go* and *started going* in this example sentence?

> "...", he said and started to go/going away.

Comment: The "act of leaving" is normally thought of as "instantaneous", so it doesn't naturally subdivide into "start", "middle", and "end" phases (you don't usually start or finish leaving). In the cited context it's more likely we'd refer to some *other* associated action that immediately precedes leaving; *"I'll see you later", said John as he **stood up** to leave*.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Start + Gerund vs Start + Infinitive: is there a subtle tense difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/381858/start-gerund-vs-start-infinitive-is-there-a-subtle-tense-difference)

Comment: ...alternatively, you might find your problems are better addressed by this English Language Learners question: [Why is it “to start laughing” and not “to start to laugh”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/35156/why-is-it-to-start-laughing-and-not-to-start-to-laugh)

Comment: Your first comment helped a lot. May I use something like "to distance", e.g. **he slowly distanced himself** to put an emphasis on the act of leaving?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using reflexive ***distance** [oneself]* for such contexts, no. That's usually a *metaphorical* usage - so you'd "distance yourself" from an ongoing argument by refusing to engage verbally, with no implication of physical movement, and it's common to hear of a politician, say, distancing himself from some vote-losing position (taking steps to avoid being associated with an unpopular opinion). Perhaps ***he slowly edged away*** would suit your context, but this is writing advice, not "grammar" as such.

Comment: I see. Thanks for explaining. I may stick to "leave" then or "to slowly edge away". It also seems good to know the difference between distance oneself and go away/leave.

Answer (score 0):

[KarlG's answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/499762/102510) to the question [Start + Gerund vs Start + Infinitive: is there a subtle tense difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/381858/102510) that FumbleFingers linked in a comment says:

> In most contexts, "*start to V*" and "*start Ving*" have the same meaning,

and then goes on to provide an example (*knocking*/*knock*) where there is very little difference. In most cases, I agree that there is little-or-no difference. However, the answer also includes:

> In her monograph *The Semantics of English Aspectual Complementation* (2012), Alice F. Freed points out that in contrast to begin, the verb start can also denote **[the onset of an action](https://books.google.de/books?id=m5fqCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA72&lpg=PA72&dq=%22started+to+sneeze+but%22&source=bl&ots=OposykQp3E&sig=ACfU3U2GUo6nShKITWaRLYWqFxptj4DReg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi-1OnV0LjiAhWLCuwKHdW-Dh4Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22started%20to%20sneeze%20but%22&f=false) without its actual completion**. To knock on a door, for instance, requires (1) approaching the door with the intention to knock, (2) raising the arm, (3) forming a fist, then (4) striking or tapping the surface of the door with the knuckles some number of times. If only the onset of the action occurs, i.e. anything or everything before (4), then the idiomatic choice can only be the marked infinitive ("*started to knock*"), not the gerund-participle ("*started knocking*").
>
> <sub>*My emphasis and parenthesized examples*</sub>

I think this subtle distinction (between the onset of an action and its completion) is particularly applicable to the case of *started to go* vs. *started going*, where (in at least some situations), the process of *going* can be a drawn-out affair.

If visitors begin to collect their possessions, say goodbye to their hosts and put on their coats, it could be said that they "*started to go [home]*", even though they have not yet left the house. Once they *have* left the house, got in their car, and are pulling away from the kerb, *then* you could say that they "*started going [home]*".

Answer (score -2):

I think both implicate the same meaning. But if *started going* is used, then **away** should be eliminated.

Comment: So **started to go away** is fine, whereas the gerund form denies "away" and it should be **started going**?

Comment: Dropping *away* in this context sounds a bit off to me. Can you establish that it “should be eliminated”?