# the to-infinitive as an adverbial(substitute of for+N?), an object, or a subject complement?

Tags: infinitives

A. She is likely/sure/certain to start her new project.

> She may start her new project.

Are the senses and the roles of the to inf. the same as 'start her new project' of 'may', complementing the (modal) verbs and indicating the action of the subject? Do we speak them in the same sense? If we classify the main verb of modal verbs ad the complement of the modal verbs, do we also classify the inf. above as the complements of the 'be + adj.'s? Or is the to-inf. just an object?

B. I'm dying/willing/curious/anxious/eager to eat that cake.

I'm dying/willing/curious/anxious/eager for that cake.

Do we speak the to inf.s above in the same sense as the 'for~'s? Do they mean
the same, expressing the subject's wish, desire, or plan as adverbials?

C. I hoped for some money./I hoped to take the train.

I begged for more candy./I begged to go to the movies.

I longed for an A./I long to get an A.

I volunteered for the job./I volunteered to help the kids.

I was aiming for the trophy./I was aiming to receive the trophy.

Do these to inf. express desire/intention as adverbials, same as the 'for+N's? Or, are they just objects?

Comment: _Sure, likely,_ and _certain_ are also [modal predicates](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Modality.pdf) (though not modal auxiliary verbs), because they express modal semantics, in this case [Epistemic modality](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/193041/15299). _Long (v), volunteer, beg, hope,_ and _aim_ express Deontic modality. In each case, the infinitive clause is a complement of the predicate, usually with _to_. Though it's not an adverbial -- it's usually a noun phrase object when it's a verbal complement.

Comment: Thank you, sir. Then, how about the one at Question B? And do Americans really think the to-infinitives after likely/sure/certain and hope/.../aim as noun phrases?

Comment: Any verb that means _want_, in one mode or another, really means _want to have_; and when we use a noun phrase (instead of a clause) as object for these verbs, they all mean _want_ (or whatever) _to have_ that noun phrase. So _dying, willing, curious, anxious,_ and _eager_ can take NP object with _for_, too.

Comment: Forgive me, sir. I've been trying to diagnose such to-infinitives but couldn't. I guess I have to ask you questions some more.

Comment: appear/seem/prove/happen/chance/turn out/have + to inf.

Comment: Is this to-inf. a subject complement acting the same as the main verb of a modal verb, or just a noun complement?

Comment: Can't tell without data. I see a list of verbs but no data. And by "subject complement" do you mean "complement of the subject" or "complement clause acting as subject"? Terminology is to describe data, not to define it.

Comment: Sorry if I used the term wrongly, sir. I meant by using it that the to-inf of 'appear/.../have' acts the same as the main verbs of modal verbs and has the same sensation. Even though you don't have any data, do you agree according to your own use of English, sir?

Comment: 'appear/.../have' is a list of verbs. What English sentences are you talking about? I can't agree to anything about grammar without knowing what it's sposta be the grammar **of**.

Comment: He appeared to be shocked./I happened to come across Tom./I don't have to attend the meeting./She tends to bite her nails./The theory proved to be telling the truth.

Comment: I think I see what you mean by "adverbial". The predicates are of various kinds. But the infinitives are just [verbal complements](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/complements.pdf). They have various analyses. Some involve [Raising or Equi](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/284751/15299); others, like _have to_, are modals.

Comment: I've posted questions below, sir. I would appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

Though you're correct that many of the pairs you've provided are similar semantically, you've confused the functions complement, object, and adjunct(traditional grammar's 'adverbial').

First off, you'll want to get form and function separated. The form of dependent clauses, and phrases, is determined by their internal structure: NPs are headed by nouns and allow a certain range of dependents; *to*-infinitival clauses are headed by a verb in plain form and allow a range of dependents different from those found in an NP. So, a *to*-infinitival clause will never be an NP, but it may appear in the same functional category in a larger structure.

Then, you can start to look at the function of these dependent clauses and phrases in clause or phrase structure.

> I
>
> She - is - **likely [to - start - her new project]**
>
> Subject - predicator - **predicative complement**

vs

> II
>
> She - may - **[start - her new project]**
>
> Subject - predicator - **catenative complement**

In I, *to start her new project* is a *to*-infinitival clause functioning as dependent (specifically a complement) in the adjective phrase headed by *likely*. It is a complement because it is allowed only by *likely* and other adjectives allowing a *to*-infinitival clause as complement, not by adjectives in general: **dry to start her new project*.

In II, *start her new project* is a plain infinitival clause functioning as direct dependent (specifically a complement) of the predicator *may*. The specific type of complement is a catenative complement. These are non-finite (plain infinitival, *to*-infinitival, gerund-participial, or past participial) clauses specifically allowed by the verb acting as predicator.

It is necessary to note here that the *to*-infinitivals in your examples are not adjuncts, but in fact complements in AdjPs in A and B, and catenative complements in C. This becomes clear when we note that *in order* may not be inserted while keeping the same meaning,

> ?I'm willing **in order to** eat that cake. (Willing to do what?)
>
> I'm dying **in order to** eat that cake. (How terrible!)
>
> etc.

> *I hoped **in order** to go to the movies.
>
> I begged **in order** to go to the movies. (What did you beg for/to do?)
>
> *I long **in order** to get an A.
>
> I volunteered **in order** to help the kids. (What did you volunteer
> for/as/to do?)
>
> I was aiming **in order** to receive the trophy. (What were you aiming
> at/to do?)

Though there is some overlap between verbs that allow different sorts of complement - object, catenative complement, predicative complement - the complements themselves are best viewed as distinct categories each allowed by a specific set of verbs. For example, what follows *get* in the each of the sentences below is a distinct sort of complement:

> Mark - got - **a dog** [object]
>
> Mark - got - **excited to go one the trip**. [predicative complement]
>
> Mark - got - **me** - **a dog** [indirect object - direct object]
>
> Mark - got - **chosen as goalie** [catenative complement(past
> participial clause)]
>
> Mark - got - **to go first** [catenative complement(*to*-infinitival
> clause)]
>
> Mark - got - **me** - **to go first** [object - catenative
> complement(*to*-infinitival clause)]

Though *get* allows these constructions, if we pick another verb that allows the first, say *sniff*, we'll quickly see that the others are not allowed.

> Mark - sniffed - **a dog** [object]
>
> *Mark - sniffed - **excited to go on the trip**. [predicative complement]
>
> *Mark - sniffed - **me** - **a dog** [indirect object - direct object]
>
> *Mark - sniffed - **chosen as goalie** [catenative complement(past
> participial clause)]
>
> *Mark - sniffed - **to go first** [catenative complement(*to*-infinitival
> clause)]
>
> *Mark - sniffed - **me** - **to go first** [object - catenative
> complement(*to*-infinitival clause)]

Though the last two could be understood as adjunct of purpose in some strange context, they are not understood in a sense similar to the catenative complement examples with *get*.

Long story short, yes all of the pairs you provided have similar meanings, no their structures cannot be analyzed as equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

hope/willingness/reluctance/anxiety/attempt + to-V

I see that this to-V is a noun complement, since the nouns' adj./v. forms take their noun complements. But...

1. opportunity/chance(s)/possibility/capacity/power + for N/to-V

   Is the to-V of opportunity/../power an adjective clause that tells us what the nouns are for?
2. 'effort' + to-V/for N

   Is the to-V of 'effort' an adjective clause that tells us the intention of the agent of 'effort'?
3. tendency+ to-V (which is the verbal complement of 'tend')

   Is the to-V of 'tendency' not a noun phrase but just a verbal complement?
4. obligation/duty/responsibility + to-V

   Is the to-V of obligation/duty/responsibility an adjective phrase that shows the fixed necessity of the agent's action?

My diagnoses of 1., 2., and 4. are on the ground that there are the usages of to infinitives as adjective phrases or adverbials that show the meanings but in just a slightly different way.

Sorry for bothering you so much, sir, but I'm having a hard time studying and diagnosing these to-Vs. There are no textbooks for learners' giving the information. (well, at least of the ones in South Korea.) I'm very thankful for your help.

Comment: You should not limit yourself to textbooks. Study the literature; read answers here. Learn how to think and talk about English syntax before you attempt to build your own version. NP complement clauses are usually related to verbal complements, and have the same range of semantic uses; (1) and (4) are modal -- (1) is epistemic, and (4) is deontic -- while (2) and (3) are essentially aspects. Complement clauses look like noun phrases from above, and clauses from below; they are actually both. Depends on where you're metaphorically standing. And this is irregular behavior. Let's stop here.

Comment: @John Lawler 'they are actually both'.  "Let's stop here" looks hopeful.