# I have analyzed a sentence. Please let me know if you see mistakes

Tags: phrases, adjectives, adverbs

For a class I am practicing analyzing sentences. This question is not my homework; it is self-directed practice. The sentence is from today's New York Times. The link is below.

- *As it resurges across the country, the coronavirus is forcing universities large and small to make deep and possibly lasting cuts to close widening budget shortfalls.*

[As it resurges across the country] Prepositional phrase acting as an adj, modifying coronavirus.
[the coronavirus] - Subject
[is forcing] - verb
[universities large and small] Indirect Object
[to make deep and possibly lasting cuts] infinitive phrase, acting as Direct Object
[to close widening budget shortfalls] infinitive phrase acting as an adjective modifying the Direct Object

Link to original sentence: https://www.nytimes.com/2020/10/26/us/colleges-coronavirus-budget-cuts.html

Comment: Aren't "universities" the direct object?

Comment: Universities ,without the description "large and small" , is a direct object.

Comment: I see you're going to collect variorum editions here.

Comment: I think you are correct about universities being the DO.

Comment: [to make dep and possibly lasting cuts] this infinitive phrase is acting as an adverb, modifying the verb, is forcing. AND [to close widening budge shortfalls] this infinitive phrase is also an acting as an adverb modifying the verb, is forcing. Anyone have different input???

Comment: I'll be answering it later, if it doesn't get closed out on me.

Answer (score 1):

> *As it resurges across the country, the coronavirus is forcing universities large and small to make deep and possibly lasting cuts to close widening budget shortfalls.*

- **Main verbs:** (1 per clause) *resurge, force, make, close*
  (we're not counting nominalizations like *shortfall* and *cut* here)
- **Major constituents:**

  1. *As it resurges across the country,*
     intransitive adverbial clause introduced by *as*
  2. *the coronavirus is forcing `S`*
     transitive main clause with direct object complement clause `S`
  3. *universities large and small to make deep and possibly lasting cuts*
     `S`, resultative complement clause of *force*
  4. *to close widening budget shortfalls*
     purpose infinitive clause (same subject as *make cuts*)

(1) is trivial; (2) is where the problem starts. Is `S` (the rest of the sentence) the object of *force*, or is the subject of `S` (the noun phrase *universities large and small*) really the object? That would be an indirect object, with the clause as its direct object.

That noun phrase *universities large and small* is sitting in exactly the right place to be either indirect object of *forcing*  or subject of *to make* -- right between the verbs, where it could be both. Certainly it is the subject noun phrase of *to make*; but is it also the object of *force*?

In other words, are you forcing the universities, or are you forcing a set of circumstances in which the universities do certain things? Both situations involve the same constructions:

- *Mary told Frank to edit his script.*
  (*Frank* is clearly the indirect object of *tell*, which requires one;
  *Frank* is also clearly the subject of *edit*.)

Here there are two propositions: Mary telling Frank something, which is reported to have happened, and Frank editing his script, which is described as the content of the telling. Frank is involved in both propositions, with different roles -- addressee in one, agent in the other. In effect, *Frank* appears twice in the sentence.

- *Mary wanted Frank to edit his script.*
  (*As before, Frank is the subject of *edit*, but is it the object of *want*?.

Here what Mary wants is not Frank, but rather his future event of script editing. In effect, *Frank* is not a part of the main clause, but rather functions only as subject of the subordinate clause. In effect, the clause itself (*for Frank to edit his script*) is the object of *want*.

Which makes sense, since *want* doesn't take an indirect object the way *tell* does. This difference goes by many names, but one such distinction is between [two rules of English syntax](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/284751/15299) called **Subject-Raising** ("Raising" for short, which applies to *want* but not to *tell*) and **Equivalent Noun Phrase Deletion** ("Equi" for short, which applies to *tell* but not to *want*).

And the question then is whether *force* takes an indirect object (hence, Equi) or whether it has a Raised object (hence, Raising). [There are syntactic tests for this condition.](http://www.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/cliffs-equi-raising.pdf)